# How to make different viewed values in ng-options and select's result

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have an angularjs's select (countries list with `name` and `code`.).

```
<select ng-model="entity.country_code"
        ng-options="c.code as c.name for c in countries">
</select>
```

I want to achieve different values in select's dropdown (when you click to select something) and in select-box (select's result).

I want to make select's dropdown to be filled with strings like "`United Kingdom (+44)`", "`Russia (+7)`".

[image]

And when user will select one of these options, I want to make select box to be filled with just digits (`+44` or `+7`).

[image]

Is it possible?

**UPD1**: Once again:

[image]

You can select `United States (+1)` in select's dropdown (left part on last image) and as a result of select you see `1` in select field (right part of image).

Comment: I dont think its possible using normal <select> You should give this library a try: http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main

Comment: Yeah, perhaps your right, I'm not sure about browsers comparability even if it's possible

Comment: That library is cross browser tested we use it in our live projects. You can start using it and if any doubts in that library I will help :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possibile, but I suggest you to use `ng-repeat` instead of `ng-options` if you want more flexibility (not sure this is the most efficient way but it's probably the most easy to understand/maintain).

Here is an example

```
<select ng-model="entity.country_code">
    <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{ country.code }}">
        {{ country.name }} (+{{ country.code }})
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not sure that it's work. At `chrome`+`mac os` at least. Still `{{ country.name }} (+{{ country.code }})` in result select field (but `entity.country_code` contains `country.code`, as planned)

Comment: you mean `{{ country.name }}` is not parsed by angular and you see it as in the code?

Answer (score 1):

You could have something like below

```
<select ng-model="entity.country_code"
     ng-options="c.code as (c.name + ' ('+ c.code + ')') for c in countries">
</select>
```

Comment: No, no, it's not about how to format a value in drop-down, it's about how to make values in drop-down looks like `c.code as (c.name + " ("+ c.code + ")")` but when you select one of value and drop-down will disappear, how to make selected value looks like `c.code` in select box

Comment: @SergeyPanfilov I'm confused, about what you have asked above?